What is the maximum length $L$ of a cylindrical plug that can be cut from a larger disc of diameter $D$ if eight plugs are cut?
A cylindrical sample of 2.25-inch outer diameter and a little over 0.25-inch height is to have 8 smaller cylindrical plugs cut from it in equal intervals of 45 degrees about its circumference as shown below. This image is the plan view of the 2.25-inch x 0.25-inch cylinder (disc).

The plugging barrel will produce cylindrical plugs that are 0.25-inch in diameter. As indicated by the dashed outline and solid double-arrow line in the image above, the resulting plug length will be dictated by the other plugs cut, i.e., where the plugging barrel will intersect with its previous cuts. What will be the length of this plug, and how to determine this value?

The little octagon in the center has side length $1/4$ (in inches), so the distance from its center to its top is $1/8 + 1/4\sqrt{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})/8$.  So the plug length is $9/8$ minus that: $1-\sqrt{2}/8\approx 0.8232$ inches.
